# "[Function: Error Ctor]" error in console

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

the first console log is getting logged but the second one isn't
and the catch is catching an error which I do not understand ...

this is my route:

```
router.post("/buy", JwtAuthenticateToken, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       
        
        const entry = new PositionModel(req.body)
        console.log("new", entry)
        const result = await entry.save()
        console.log("saved", result)
        
        
    } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)

        next(error)
    }
})
```

this is what gets printed in the console:

```
new {
  _id: 6125514a26fb7d06603b1a5a,
  stock: 'Apple Inc',
  ticker: 'AAPL',
  purchasePrice: 149.62,
  shares: 1,
  owner: 6124e2a70d195a05f4e480cd
}
[Function: ErrorCtor]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was passing an error to an error creator in my .post("validate")
probably the dumbest 5 lines of code I have ever written.

```
post("validate", (error, doc, next) => {
    if (error) {
        const err = createError(400, error)
        next(err)
    } else {
        next(error)
    }
})
```